# xming 7.7.0.23 OpenGl version reported incorrectly

Tags: opengl, xming

I'm trying to use xming to render software using OpenGl running on the same machine in WSL / windows bash.

This works fine for some really small demos, however once I try something like glmark2, it fails because it seems the OpenGl version is reported incorrectly.

`glxinfo | grep OpenGL` reports this:

```
OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: GeForce GTX 970M/PCIe/SSE2
OpenGL version string: 1.4 (4.5.0 NVIDIA 382.05)
```

If I let xming run on my internal graphics card (using a laptop), it reports

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel
OpenGL renderer string: Intel(R) HD Graphics 4600
OpenGL version string: 1.4 (4.3.0 - Build 20.19.15.4568)
```

The weird part is the `1.4` in front of `4.5.0 NVIDIA 382.05`.
The OpenGl support is definitely at least 3, because a demo using GLSL shaders which require newer OpenGl runs, but the version string is kinda garbage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're running into is, that the GLX portion of XMing does support only up to OpenGL-1.4. The part inside the parentheses is the version string as reported by the system native OpenGL implementation. However since XMing lacks (so far) the capability to **reliably** pass on anything beyond OpenGL-1.4 it will simply tell you "all I guarantee you to support is OpenGL 1.4, *but the system I'm running on could actually do …*".

Maybe some day someone goes through the effort to implement a fully featured dynamic GLX←→WGL wrapper.

Comment: So this is the reason my demo using OpenGl shaders actually works, but the reported GL_VERSION is still 1.4?
Also I read about MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE and tried setting it higher, but it does not seem to change anything.

Comment: @olee: Mesa has hardly any say in this – except for offering a software rasterizer implementation if demands can not be fulfilled natively. Technically speaking you should try to run your program natively. As much as I have a soft spot for the X11 protocol (warts and all), if you require modern OpenGL support the only viable choice these days is to go native.